# Is possible to write an xposed module that hides the recent apps button in Android?

Tags: navigation, android-recents, xposed-framework

I wonder, is it possible to write an xposed module (xposed framework module) that can completely remove the recent apps button from the navigation bar or all completely disable the recent apps selection activity?

Everyone are free to write xposed modules, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xposed can modify **any** part of android you'd like. So yes you can completely remove the recent apps button and more.

Anyone can write xposed modules.

Comment: OK excellent. I actually managed to write a module that hides those buttons. The problem I had was, of course, that different Android versions having those buttons be a bit differently implemented, but I believe I have made something that is fairly universal.